# How to get the href when they're isn't in the code source?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape all the href for those watches :

https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/marques/cartier/

But, for example, when I want to find where the first url is : https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier/

I use ctrl-f and I cannot find it anywhere. How could I scrape something I cannot find in the code source ?

Answer (score 0):

The ***href*** attribute of the *`<a>`* contains the desired values. Though the values when extracted would appear as:

```
https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier/
```

but when accessed as a *url_string* would be converted as:

```
https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier/
```

---

### Solution

To extract the value of *`href`* attributes you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/marques/cartier/")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.woocommerce-LoopProduct-link.woocommerce-loop-product__link[href]")))])
  ```
- Using *XPATH*_:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/marques/cartier/")
  print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link' and @href]")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-2/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-3/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-4/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-5/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-6/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-7/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/montre-pasha-de-cartier-8/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-grand-modele-2/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-grand-modele-3/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-grand-modele/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-grand-modele-4/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-10/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-9/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-7/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-6/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-5/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-8/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-2/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-4/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-mini-modele-3/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele-2/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele-4/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele-3/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele-5/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele-6/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/baignoire-petit-modele-7/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-blanc-de-cartier-2/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-blanc-de-cartier-3/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-blanc-de-cartier/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-50/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-51/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-65/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-95/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-96/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-41/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-25/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-2/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-28/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-94/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-34/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-27/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-35/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-93/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-29/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-26/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-58/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-10/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-3/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-33/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-67/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-23/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-16/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-20/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-43/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-80/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-11/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-57/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-77/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-31/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-21/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-82/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-56/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-90/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-52/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-91/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-54/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-89/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-53/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-8/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-55/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-83/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-62/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-6/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-4/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-87/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-5/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-88/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-86/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-40/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-39/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-92/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-36/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-47/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-19/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-75/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-9/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-46/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-70/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/marques/cartier/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-13/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-15/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-45/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-71/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-79/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-76/', 'https://www.godechot-pauliet.com/produit/best-sellers/ballon-bleu-de-cartier-37/']
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```